# Conditional styling using Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I've been trying for hours to figure this out, and I'm sure the answer is simple. When an Item is clicked, it will ultimately create a filter for my todo list. What I'm struggling to do is apply conditional styling, so that the font color of the 'active' item is blue.

I have included `status` as a prop, but I can't seem to use it as well as props inside the styled components.

From my App.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [ status, setStatus ] = useState("all")

  return (
    <Filter status={status} setStatus={setStatus}/>
  )
}
```

Filter.js

```
const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
`

const Item = styled.p`
   color: red;

   // I'm trying to do something like this..

   ${(status, props) => {
        if (status === props.id) {
            return `
                color: blue;
            `
        }
    }}
   
`

export const Filter = ({ setStatus, status }) => {
    
    const statusHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.target.id) {
            setStatus(e.target.id)        
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
          <Container onClick={statusHandler}>
            <Item id="all">All</Item>
            <Item id="active">Active</Item>
            <Item id="completed">Completed</Item>
          </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where does `props.id` come from? I see the status coming in as `status={status}` but don't see an ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass both the `status` and `id` props to the `Item` component and do the comparison in the props callback.

```
const Item = styled.p`
  color: red;

  ${({ id, status }) => status === id && 'color: blue; '}
`;
```

Usage:

```
<Item id="all" status={status}>All</Item>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit conditional-styling-using-styled-components]

You *could* make this simpler though with a single prop and do the conditional test in the component.

```
const Item = styled.p`
  color: red;

  ${({ isStatusMatch }) => isStatusMatch && "color: blue;"}
`;

...

<Item isStatusMatch={status === 'all'}>All</Item>
```

Full demo code:

```
const Item = styled.p`
  color: red;
  ${({ id, status }) => status === id && "color: blue;"}
`;

const Item2 = styled.p.attrs(({ id, status }) => ({
  className: id === status && "statusMatch"
}))`
  color: red;
  &.statusMatch {
    color: blue;
  }
`;

const Item3 = styled.p`
  color: red;
  ${({ statusMatch }) => statusMatch && "color: blue;"}
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Item id="test" status="test">
        test
      </Item>
      <Item id="nottest" status="test">
        not test
      </Item>

      <Item2 id="test" status="test">
        test
      </Item2>
      <Item2 id="nottest" status="test">
        not test
      </Item2>

      <Item3 statusMatch={"test" === "test"}>test</Item3>
      <Item3 statusMatch={"nottest" === "test"}>not test</Item3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to perform this task is to add a class at the element you want to change the color.

So you're item will be

```js
const Item = styled.p`
   color: black;
   &.selected {
    color: red
   }
```

and you're Component will be:

```js
<>
    <Item id="all" className={status === "all" ? "selected" : null}>All</Item>
    <Item id="active" className={status === "active" ? "selected" : null}>Active</Item>
    <Item id="completed" className={status === "completed" ? "selected" : null}>Completed</Item>
</>
```

To avoid to write repeating code you can loop the values. And here we go:

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: "all",
        value: "All"
    },
    {
        id: "active",
        value: "Active"
    },
    {
        id: "completed",
        value: "Completed"
    },
]

items.map(({id, value}) => (
    <Item key={id} id={id} className={status === id ? "selected" : null}>{value}</Item>
))
```

There's no need to put logic in Styled Component if you can keep in React

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
// YOUR STYLES
const activeStyles = (props) => ({
  color: props.status === props.id ? 'blue' : null
});

// YOUR FILTER COMPONENT
    return (
        <div>
          <Container onClick={statusHandler}>
            <Item id="all" styles={{...activeStyles({status, id:'all'})}}>All</Item>
            <Item id="active" styles={{...activeStyles({status, id:'active'})}}>Active</Item>
            <Item id="completed" styles={{...activeStyles({status, id:'completed'})}}>Completed</Item>
          </Container>
        </div>
    )
```